# A rude/street-model equivalent for "He afraids of me too much"

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one of the following sentences (or probabely your suggested one which would sound more suited to the case in my question) is commonly used to imply that someone is really scares of you?

> - He is scared shitless of me.
> - He has a healthy fear of me.
> - I put the fear of God in his heart.

The concept in my question is very informal and even rude which using it can sound offensive to the scared person!)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an informal and “rude” (or crude) way to express that someone is afraid of you, your first sentence would work (though it’s spelled *shitless*). You could also say this if you want to emphasize how responsible you are for his fear:

> I scare the *crap* out of him.

You can substitute a strong expletive for *crap* to make the statement more vulgar.